# Every Tab is having same data in the recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

[image: TabscreenShot]hi everyone i have created tabs using JSONS each tab contains recycler view where the required data of that tab will be displayed there but where as in output same data is displaying in every tab and also one item is displaying in it

JSON

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "Menu is Listed Here",
    "menu1": [{
        "category": "Women",
        "items": [{
            "id": "41",
            "title": "Plain Classic Abaya "
        }, {
            "id": "45",
            "title": "Modest Abaya Collection "
        }, {
            "id": "48",
            "title": "Khaleejia Abaya  "
        }, {
            "id": "53",
            "title": "Modern Jersy Classic Abaya"
        }, {
            "id": "54",
            "title": "Sophisticated Abayas"
        }, {
            "id": "55",
            "title": "Khaleejia Kaftans "
        }, {
            "id": "56",
            "title": "Jersey Maxi Kaftans "
        }, {
            "id": "57",
            "title": "Wedding Abaya"
        }, {
            "id": "58",
            "title": "Latest Trend Abaya"
        }]
    }, {
        "category": "Kids",
        "items": [{
            "id": "40",
            "title": "Girls Abaya Plain "
        }, {
            "id": "52",
            "title": "Girls Abaya Modern designs "
        }]
    }, {
        "category": "Men",
        "items": [{
            "id": "42",
            "title": "Modern Stylish Thobes "
        }, {
            "id": "46",
            "title": "Embroidery Thobes  "
        }, {
            "id": "47",
            "title": "Simple Plain Thobes "
        }]
    }],
    "wholesale": "Wholesale Products"
}
```

TabsFragment.java

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recycler_view;
    Recycler_Adapter recycler_adapter;

    public TabsFragment() {

    }

    public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
        OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        recycler_view = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
        catmethod();
        return view;
    }

    private void catmethod() {
        String url = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/categories.php";
        JsonObjectRequest catreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menuarray = response.getJSONArray("menu1");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject menuobj = menuarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray itemarray = menuobj.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int j = 0; j < itemarray.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject itemobj = itemarray.getJSONObject(j);
                            TestPojo test = new TestPojo();
                            test.setIdstring(itemobj.getString("id"));
                            test.setTitlestring(itemobj.getString("title"));
                            recycler_adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(), itemarray);
                            recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            recycler_view.setAdapter(recycler_adapter);
                            recycler_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("CatMenu", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(catreq);
    }

}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

    public Recycler_Adapter(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View namelist = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(namelist);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                String idname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("id");
                String titlename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("title");

                holder.cat_item_id.setText(idname);
                holder.cat_item_name.setText(titlename);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    List<TestPojo> testlit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        testlit=new ArrayList<TestPojo>();
        catmethod();
    }
    private void catmethod() {
        String url = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/categories.php";
        JsonObjectRequest catreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menuarray = response.getJSONArray("menu1");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject menuobj = menuarray.getJSONObject(i);
                     tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(menuobj.getString("category")));
test.setTitlestring(itemobj.getString("title"));
                     }
                    }
                    TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), menuarray);
                    viewpager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
                    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("CatMenu", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(catreq);
    }
}
```

TabsAdapter.class

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager manager, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        super(manager);
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return OneFragment.getInstance(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String stringarray= null;
        try {
            stringarray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("category");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringarray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Adapter:

```
public class Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    private List<TestPojo> list;

    public Recycler_Adapter(Context context, List list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list= list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View namelist = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(namelist);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {   
                 TestPojo testpojo = list.get(position);
                holder.cat_item_id.setText(testpojo.getId());
                holder.cat_item_name.setText(testpojo.getTitle());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.length();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    List<TestPojo> testlit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        testlit=new ArrayList<TestPojo>();
        catmethod();
    }
    private void catmethod() {
        String url = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/categories.php";
        JsonObjectRequest catreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray menuarray = response.getJSONArray("menu1");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject menuobj = menuarray.getJSONObject(i);
                     tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(menuobj.getString("category")));
test.setTitlestring(itemobj.getString("title"));
                     }
                    }
                    TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), menuarray);
                    viewpager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
                    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("CatMenu", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(catreq);
    }
}
```

Use position in TestFragment:

```
private void catmethod() {
            String url = "http://www.souqalkhaleejia.com/webapis/categories.php";
            int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
            JsonObjectRequest catreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray menuarray = response.getJSONArray("menu1");
                            JSONObject menuobj = menuarray.getJSONObject(position);
                            JSONArray itemarray = menuobj.getJSONArray("items");
                            List<TestPojo> objList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < itemarray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject itemobj = itemarray.getJSONObject(j);
                                TestPojo test = new TestPojo();
                                test.setIdstring(itemobj.getString("id"));
                                test.setTitlestring(itemobj.getString("title"));
                                objList.add(test);
                            }
                            recycler_adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(), objList);
                            recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            recycler_view.setAdapter(recycler_adapter);
                            recycler_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("CatMenu", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(catreq);
        }
```

Remove the loop.Or you will get all row to show the last data.
And you should use getArguments().getInt("position", 0) in catmethod().

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
            String idname = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("id");
            String titlename = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("title");

            holder.cat_item_id.setText(idname);
            holder.cat_item_name.setText(titlename);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code blew should used only once in TestFragment.You should not put them in loop.

```
recycler_adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(), itemarray);
                                recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                                recycler_view.setAdapter(recycler_adapter);
                                recycler_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
```

Where did you use that position.You get this position to select what data to show in every tab 0=>women,1=>kids,2=>men. But where did you use it? 
Please try to use the positoin in catmethod of TestFragment.

Comment: Plz read catmethod in TestFragment and write the use of every line.

Comment: I'm going to sleep now.If you can write the use of each line,you can get corret result.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < menuarray.length(); i++) {JSONObject menuobj = menuarray.getJSONObject(i);JSONArray itemarray =menuobj.getJSONArray("items");for (int j = 0; j < itemarray.length();j++) {recycler_adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(), itemarray);recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));recycler_view.setAdapter(recycler_adapter);recycler_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}}getArguments().getInt("position", 0);

Comment: yes sir your correct but not able to understand where use the position sir

Comment: yes sir it worked but only first item is displaying sir

Comment: JSONArray menuarray =response.getJSONArray("menu1");
JSONObject menuobj=menuarray.getJSONObject(position);
JSONArray itemarray = menuobj.getJSONArray("items");
for (int j = 0; j < itemarray.length(); j++) {JSONObject itemobj = itemarray.getJSONObject(j);TestPojo testpoko = new TestPojo();
testpoko.setIdstring(itemobj.getString("id"));testpoko.setTitlestring(itemobj.getString("title"));tetslist.add(testpoko);Log.d("JsonArray",String.valueOf(itemarray));}} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recycler_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105713/discussion-between-tiny-sunlight-and-prominere).